# What is wrong with this syntax of a multi-table DELETE...ORDER BY?

Tags: mysql, join, mariadb, delete, order-by

I have the following query:

```
DELETE proxies, pxpl FROM proxies
JOIN proxy_xref_proxy_list AS pxpl ON proxies.ID=pxpl.ProxyID
WHERE pxpl.DeactivationTS < (NOW() - INTERVAL 24 HOUR)
ORDER BY pxpl.ProxyListID, proxies.ID
```

The ordering is needed to avoid DB deadlocks.
However, it yields an error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'ORDER BY pxpl.ProxyListID, proxies.ID' at line 4

`proxy_xref_proxy_list` is a many-to-many relation association table.

Comment: Is that join (`ON proxies.ID=pxpl.ProxyID`) on a foreign key? Show us the definitions of the tables, please.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ, please, see the definitions of the tables in another my question: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/268954/why-do-these-queries-deadlock-and-how-to-work-this-around-in-mariadb .  Yes, `pxpl.ProxyID` is a foreign key into `proxies` table (column `ID`). Also, `pxpl.ProxyListID` is a foreign key.

Answer (score 1):

(Serge self-Answered the title question; this Answer tries to look beyond that.)

If the deadlock is caused by the *same* `DELETE` being run from multiple threads, then simply ignore the deadlock; the other thread will do the work.

If there are other concerns, there are ways to use subqueries instead of a JOIN.  There is even a kludge where an extra level of subquery is a workaround for another error you may encounter.

If you have massive deletes, then see this for tips: http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, `ORDER BY` is not supported in a multi-delete query, [according to the doc](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/delete/):

> For the multiple-table syntax, DELETE deletes from each tbl_name the
>   rows that satisfy the conditions. In this case, ORDER BY and LIMIT>
>   cannot be used. A DELETE can also reference tables which are located
>   in different databases; see Identifier Qualifiers for the syntax.

Answer (score 0):

One problem I see is that your `DELETE` will try to delete from both tables when a row exists in pxpl with `WHERE pxpl.DeactivationTS < (NOW() - INTERVAL 24 HOUR)`. But the related row (through the FK) in `proxies` maybe related to more rows in `pxpl` that do not match the criteria. And because the FK has `ON DELETE CASCADE`, it will try to delete them as well. That maybe one reason for the deadlocks you see (when there is no `ORDER BY`).

You can try to delete only from the parent table and let the cascade action do its work and delete all the ratled rows in the child table, say with:

```
DELETE FROM proxies 
WHERE EXISTS
  ( SELECT 1 
    FROM proxy_xref_proxy_list AS pxpl 
    WHERE proxies.ID = pxpl.ProxyID
      AND pxpl.DeactivationTS < (NOW() - INTERVAL 24 HOUR)
  ) ;
```

You could even use `ORDER BY` this way, although I don't think you need it.